# Excel import check Sheet password

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I'm using EPPlus to create excel file with some restriction (lock, validation,..) and I have set a password for the sheet:

```
sheet.Protection.IsProtected = true;
sheet.Protection.SetPassword("pass");
```

Users have to make some changes in the file and import the same file.

How can i check when importing file that the password is the same ("pass") 
using EPPLUS? I want to be sure that user use and import the same Excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not really a way to do specifically what you're asking regarding checking the password. However, your real question is how to authenticate against user unethical behavior to ensure they are using the proper template. There are LOTS of ways to do this. I defend against this frequently, particularly users in the India region (not racist just a statistical reality!).

May I suggest a different strategy of creating a hidden tab/Name or something to authenticate that the user is using the right workbook? There are lots of ways to do this by checking the author/hidden ranges/ etc.

Here's an example if you had a hidden range named `yeaMan`. I'd put this in a sheet that's `VeryHidden` to make it difficult for users to find. It's not invincible, but it'll thwart probably 95% of unethical behavior.

```
Sub CheckIfLegit()
Dim nHunter As String, NN As Name, OkayToSubmit As Boolean
nHunter = "yeaMan"

'searches for named range (could also be a veryhidden sheet or a variety of other tools)
For Each NN In ThisWorkbook.Names
    If InStr(1, NN.Name, nHunter, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        OkayToSubmit = True
        Exit For
    End If

Next NN

'test if the range was found
If OkayToSubmit Then
    'OKAY TO SUBMIT! Run your submission code!
Else
    MsgBox "Listen fool, you've been up to no good and I caught your @$$! Access Denied!!!", vbCritical, Title:="Oh NO!!!"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer; i'm gonna use a hidden sheet to check if the file is my original file.